# Google docs : does it exist some models in HTML or other webformat to publish a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I've tested the API of Google to interact with Google doc (Calendar, Spreadsheet, etc) and everything runs correctly. However, I wonder if there is a framework that implements some model in HTML or an other web format to publish/visualize a calendar or a spreadsheet within a web page. My goal is to integrate a spreadsheet/calendar into a web page and then a user can modify the values of this spreadsheet/calendar.

Does it exist something similar to my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **spreadsheets**, the Google answer [Publishing: Embedding a spreadsheet in your blog or webpage](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244) explains what you have to do. Especially the last sentence is important:

> If you want to embed a form in a
>   website or blog, click the More
>   Actions button at the top of the
>   editor, and select the 'Embed' option
>   from the drop-down menu.

But don't forget all the steps listed above this.

For **Google Calendar**, there's [Embed on your Website - Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207), another answer from Google, that even contains a slideshow that shows what you have to do.

Comment: Thanks but it's only to publish a spreadsheet. I can not modify my spreadsheet with this solution. I only can see...

Comment: OK, how would you determine who can edit the spreadsheet? Any visitor of your site? A logged-in user? It might be (a lot) easier to give them access through a link, instead of embedding.

Comment: A user thah has been authentificated before... I'd like integrate everything in my web page, I don't want to set a link...

Do you know a solution?

thanks

Comment: It might not be possible without resorting to an iframe.